# Connect to elasticsearch using eclipse

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a student and keen in learning elasticsearch, I could run and create index in elasticsearch from browser but can you give me detailed step by step guide to connect elasticsearch using eclipse and the code used to connect and create index.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have phrased the question, the clear answer is no.